# Specific renaming of elements in Attribute table failing until closing and reopen attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, ux

Well the title tells it already. I have a column name and 100 objects. I have given them all a name. Now I mentioned that I have written some wrong of them. So I tried to correct them by double click and rename. But when I leave the name it remains the old name. I need to close the Attribute table and reopen it, then I see that it has taken the name.

This happen just to some of my entries! Most are working properly and change is done without reopening.

I just want to know if it's a bug or a feature :D I mean I know know that he just do not show it to me. But it's a bug that can be easily fixed I think.

Comment: Same here, seems like a bug. It only happens if you have sorted the objects by the column you want to change. Other columns behave normal.

Comment: Ohh good to know, could you write a bug report this maybe?

Comment: Under heavy load :D well no wonder that noone posting issues there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug and has already a ticket:

https://hub.qgis.org/issues/10976

Hopefully it can be resolved for QGIS 2.8 which will be out soon.

Comment: Awesome! This little but happened to me a couple of times, looking forward to testing 2.8.